# AOSP build error: No config file found for TARGET_DEVICE

Tags: android, makefile, build, device, android-source

I have just set up syncing the repo, trying to build AOSP for my Sprout4. I have added my own device tree n device/google/sprout4 and device/google/sprout-common

I am adding a lunch combo of `full_sprout4-userdebug` in vendorsetup.sh. However when I run lunch I get this error

```
build/core/envsetup.mk:212: *** No config file found for TARGET_DEVICE sprout4 generic.  Stop.
```

What's weird is that it is parsing my device name wrong. It should be `sprout4` and not `sprout4-generic`, but I have no idea where that `generic` is coming from.

Here is my `full_sprout4.mk`

```
PRODUCT_NAME := full_sprout4
PRODUCT_DEVICE := sprout4
PRODUCT_BRAND := Android
PRODUCT_MODEL := AOSP on sprout4
PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER := google
PRODUCT_RESTRICT_VENDOR_FILES := false

# Overlays
DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/overlay

# common sprout
$(call inherit-product, device/google/sprout-common/sprout.mk)

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/init.sprout.rc:root/init.sprout.rc \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/fstab.sprout:root/fstab.sprout
```

Here's the `sprout.mk` in `sprout-common` folder

```
# Prebuilt Kernel
ifeq ($(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL),)
LOCAL_KERNEL := device/google/sprout-common/kernel
else
LOCAL_KERNEL := $(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL)
endif

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := \
    $(LOCAL_KERNEL):kernel

# GPS
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
     $(LOCAL_PATH)/configs/agps_profiles_conf2.xml:system/etc/agps_profiles_conf2.xml \

# Audio 
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/media_profiles.xml:system/etc/media_profiles.xml \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/media_codecs.xml:system/etc/media_codecs.xml \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml:system/etc/media_codecs_performance.xml \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/audio_policy.conf:system/etc/audio_policy.conf \
    frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/data/media_codecs_google_audio.xml:system/etc/media_codecs_google_audio.xml \
    frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/data/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml:system/etc/media_codecs_google_telephony.xml \
    frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/data/media_codecs_google_video_le.xml:system/etc/media_codecs_google_video_le.xml

# Permissions
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.bluetooth_le.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.bluetooth_le.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.bluetooth.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.bluetooth.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.camera.flash-autofocus.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.camera.flash-autofocus.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.camera.front.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.camera.front.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.camera.manual_sensor.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.camera.manual_sensor.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.faketouch.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.faketouch.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.location.gps.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.location.gps.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.compass.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.compass.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.light.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.light.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.proximity.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.proximity.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.telephony.gsm.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.telephony.gsm.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.touchscreen.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.touchscreen.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.wifi.direct.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.wifi.direct.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.wifi.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.wifi.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.software.midi.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.software.midi.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/android.software.sip.voip.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.software.sip.voip.xml \
    frameworks/native/data/etc/handheld_core_hardware.xml:system/etc/permissions/handheld_core_hardware.xml \
    packages/wallpapers/LivePicker/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.software.live_wallpaper.xml

# Thermal
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
     $(LOCAL_PATH)/configs/thermal.conf:system/etc/.tp/thermal.conf
     $(LOCAL_PATH)/configs/.ht120.mtc:system/etc/.tp/.ht120.mtc
     $(LOCAL_PATH)/configs/thermal.off.conf:system/etc/.tp/thermal.off.conf

# Keylayout
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/usr/keylayout/mtk-kpd.kl:system/usr/keylayout/mtk-kpd.kl \

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/hostapd/hostapd_default.conf:system/etc/hostapd/hostapd_default.conf \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept:system/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/system/etc/hostapd/hostapd.deny:system/etc/hostapd/hostapd.deny

PRODUCT_TAGS += dalvik.gc.type-precise

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/init.sprout_common.rc:root/init.sprout_common.rc \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/sbin/multi_init:root/sbin/multi_init \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/init.protect.rc:root/init.protect.rc \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/init.modem.rc:root/init.modem.rc \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/factory_init.rc:root/factory_init.rc \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/ueventd.sprout.rc:root/ueventd.sprout.rc \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/init.sprout.usb.rc:root/init.sprout.usb.rc

# Correct bootanimation size for the screen
TARGET_SCREEN_HEIGHT := 854
TARGET_SCREEN_WIDTH := 480

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rootdir/root/twrp.fstab:recovery/root/etc/twrp.fstab

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    audio.a2dp.default \
    audio.usb.default \
    audio.r_submix.default \
    libaudio-resampler \
    tinymix

# USE_CUSTOM_AUDIO_POLICY := 1

PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += \
    ro.telephony.ril_class=SproutRIL

# FM Radio
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    FMRadioGoogle \
    FmRadioTrampoline2

# Wifi
 PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    libwpa_client \
    hostapd \
    dhcpcd.conf \
    wpa_supplicant \
    wpa_supplicant.conf

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    libsprout

PRODUCT_DEFAULT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += \
    camera.disable_zsl_mode=1

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    librs_jni \
    com.android.future.usb.accessory

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    charger \
    charger_res_images \
    libnl_2 \
    libtinyxml

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    setup_fs \
    e2fsck \

# Dynamically set props
PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_BLACKLIST := \
    ro.product.name \
    ro.product.manufacturer \
    ro.product.model

PRODUCT_AAPT_CONFIG := normal hdpi
PRODUCT_AAPT_PREF_CONFIG := hdpi

# call the proprietary setup
$(call inherit-product, vendor/google/sprout/sprout-vendor.mk)

$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/languages_full.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/full_base_telephony.mk)
$(call inherit-product, frameworks/native/build/phone-xhdpi-1024-dalvik-heap.mk)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this in case someone comes wondering about the same question later sometime.

I am building AOSP Pie. Got same error. The issue was missing BoardConfig.mk file. Create that with proper ARCH variants and you are good to go.

Comment: Might be worth adding an example here for the original example.